# c# regex long pattern with length test

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need help using regex in c#. I have a string

```
a= lF-rwn-8343775
b= Mr. Roshan K. Gujarathi
```

I want  regex pattern to match this and get a bool value in c# I have tried a pattern like this

```
return Regex.IsMatch(a, @"([a-zA-Z])-([0-9])*$");
return Regex.IsMatch(b, @"([a-zA-Z]). ([a-zA-Z]) ([a-zA-Z]). ([a-zA-Z])*$");
```

I have also tried `return Regex.IsMatch(a, @"([a-zA-Z])-([a-zA-Z])-([0-9])*$");` for the a but no use

But this is showing as false. I want to match the length in a i.e.,

first 2 char then - then 2 char - then 8 int and same for the name like 
2-4 char Then . 10-15 char then 'space' then 1 char. then 10-15 char

Comment: I am not exactly following what you are after, but in regex, you have the `{min, max}` operator. So `[a-z]{2,3}` would mean a minimum of 2, and a maximum of 3 letters.

Comment: Paste your regex'es into [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and check the explanation to see if they're what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but actually I don't know that so asked a question sorry... @npinti

Comment: You're ignoring the 'rwn'  in the first regex, is this intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use anchors in your patterns (`^` and `$`)
2. Put quantifiers wherever possible.
3. Avoid using a grouping match if you do not want them

So, it should work as:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(a, @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{8}$");
return Regex.IsMatch(b, @"^[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\. [a-zA-Z]{10,15} [a-zA-Z]\. [a-zA-Z]{10,15}$");
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @hjpotter92 this is what exactly I was looking for thanks for your help mate thanks

Comment: `\\.`? why the escape ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub `.` by itself will match any character in regex. To match a literal period `.` character, it needs to be escaped.

Comment: @Roshan If the post helped, you can select it as an answer.

Comment: I know that, my question was badly asked, why you you escape the backslash within a literal string? (also, you forgot to escape the last `.`)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Ah! I was not aware about literal strings in C#. I thought `@` was there to suppress warnings (like it does in PHP). Updating the answer now. Thanks!

Comment: Still, why didn't you escape the last dot? (you have my upvote anyway ;) )

Comment: @ThomasAyoub That was a mere oversight.